# How do you apply one action to multiple Sprites in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, action

If I've got a dude at the top of my screen, and a dude who comes in later at the bottom, and I want them both to move to the left of the screen using my `moveToLeftOfScreen` action I've created, how do I do that?

If I've got var `moveToLeftOfScreen = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:blhabhla, y:bhlahbla, duration: 3))` that won't allow something to move to the left in a straight line from where it spawns.

Long story short: Can you make a single action that says **"Move to the left until you hit the screen, then move back to the right until you hit the screeN"** and apply that to things spawning in at different locations at different times and then just apply that action when needed throughout your code instead of writing a different action for every single height.

Comment: In short, no you can't. You still need to have a a trigger to do something else. If you do not define that trigger, your code will be clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to sangony, I would have thought this is very possible, though I may be missing something.

Could you not create a reference to an `SKAction` that is a sequence of move to X=0 and move to X=size.width? and repeat if forever.

I'm not near my mac so I cant get the syntax perfect in XCode so apologies for any errors. Also this assumes that the scene will create this reference, hence the `self.size.width`:

```
let moveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: 3)
let moveRight = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width, duration: 3)
let moveLeftThenRight = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, moveRight])
let continousMovement = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeftThenRight)
```

Apply that final action to any node that spawns and you should be ok if I understand you correctly.

There will be an issue with the first movement being slow as it will always take 3 seconds to move to the left regardless of where the node spawns. This can be fixed by getting the fraction of the distance it needs to move and multiplying it by 3:

```
let firstMovementDuration = (node.position.x / self.size.width) * 3
let firstMoveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: firstMovementDuration)
```

And from there continue with normal movement. There's also the `timingMode` to consider for more natural movement such as `.EaseInEaseOut`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks for taking the time to type all of that out. 
I wasn't even aware there was just a moveToX vs moveTo (brand spanking new to coding) haha...pretty obvious now.

And yeah great idea with multiplying. 

Have a good one!